# Looking for Chromakey library in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, chromakey

I was wondering if anyone knows of a library for chromakey that is written in Java?
I am looking to edit the contents of a green screen image using Java to compliment an existing Java development.
I know that there is a C library known as open-CV that provides this ability and much more, and was hoping someone could point me towards a JAVA equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists [`JavaCV`](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/).

> JavaCV first provides wrappers to commonly used libraries by researchers in the field of computer vision: OpenCV, FFmpeg, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, and ARToolKitPlus.

---

Also take a look at `JAI` (Java Advanced Imaging API), and have a look at [this link](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6520-howto-chromakey.jsp) from the [Java Image Processing Cookbook](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/index.jsp). Note that JAI is a bit hard to find, hidden somewhere in the Oracle's Java website.

---

My opinion is that Java lacks a lot in the more scientific communities applications field. I haven't seen anything much satisfactory for computer vision done in Java. If you want to go towards Computer Vision and more advanced stuff, but still want Java, take a look at [`Processing`](http://processing.org/). If not, switch to `C\C++` or `Python`.

Here is an interesting [blog post](http://blog.samibadawi.com/2008/09/computer-vision-c-vs-java-review.html)

Comment: Cheers c00kiemon5ter, the links on this post were very very helpful. I have got something up and working reasonably well already. Thank you.