# Chroma key effect in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I also need to find a library which allows to implement the "chroma key" effect in Java. The video contains some part in green color, which is replaced which a picture during the rendering in order to create a new video.

I am linking my question with a similar question which was already answered but with uncomplete answer ([Looking for Chromakey library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283861/looking-for-chromakey-library-in-java/8501791)). Could you please specify how did you do to have something up and working so quickly? I have been unsuccessful for some months fighting against the same issue.

[c00kiemon5ter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329407/c00kiemon5ter) pointed several resources:

- JavaCV
- JAI (Java Advanced Imaging API)
- Java Image Processing Cookbook

Which one did work for you?

Comment: `I am linking my question with a similar question which was already answered but with uncomplete answer.`. I see no such link.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know how to link both questions. Finally I have added the link in the body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for Chromakey library in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283861/looking-for-chromakey-library-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) contains lots of methods to process video streams.

This code should get you started: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/59118 but it's probably too slow in Java. Try this approach:

Create a filter which turns all the green pixels into a mask (look for things that "select by color").

Use the mask to copy the background image into the video.

Comment: Sorry Aaron, I do not know how to do that. Some code excerpt or links would be appreciated, if you have them available.

Comment: Sorry, no canned solution available. You will have to invest a few hours yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute with a piece of code which gave me quite good results. I wonder if I used the classes and methods that Aaron Digulla suggested.

Please note that in this case my video has black background, that is why I am replacing the black color with the background image. I expect to obtain better results when I can edit the video to have green background, because black color is more likely to be used within the video main characters and replacing wrong pixels causes a quite awful effect.

--

```
package transparentvideo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.awt.image.ImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.awt.image.RGBImageFilter;
import java.io.File;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TransparentVideo
{
Player mediaPlayer;

JFrame invisibleFrame;
JFrame visibleFrame;
JLabel videoScreen;
JPanel offScreenVideo;

String backgroundImageFile="nature.jpg";

String videoFile="girl.mov";

public TransparentVideo() 
{

    invisibleFrame = new JFrame();

    invisibleFrame.setSize(400, 400);

    Container container=invisibleFrame.getContentPane();
    offScreenVideo =  getvidComp();
    offScreenVideo.setPreferredSize(container.getSize());
    offScreenVideo.setVisible(true);

    container.add(offScreenVideo);
    invisibleFrame.setVisible(true);

    visibleFrame=new JFrame();
    visibleFrame.setSize(container.getSize());
    visibleFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    videoScreen = new JLabel();

    visibleFrame.getContentPane().add(videoScreen);

    visibleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    visibleFrame.setVisible(true);

    invisibleFrame.setVisible(false);

    try 
    {
        while(true)
        {

            if(mediaPlayer.getState()==Player.Started)
                reDraw();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}


public void reDraw()
{
      BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(videoScreen.getWidth(), videoScreen.getHeight(),
              BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

      bi.getGraphics().drawImage(new ImageIcon(backgroundImageFile).getImage(), 0 , 0 ,
              videoScreen.getWidth(), videoScreen.getHeight(), null);

      BufferedImage screenShot = createImage((JComponent) offScreenVideo, 
              new Rectangle(invisibleFrame.getBounds()));
      Image im = makeColorTransparent(new ImageIcon(screenShot).getImage(), Color.BLACK);

      bi.getGraphics().drawImage(im, 0 ,0 , videoScreen.getWidth(), videoScreen.getHeight(), null);

      videoScreen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));

}



public static BufferedImage createImage(Component component, Rectangle region) 
{

    if (!component.isDisplayable()) {
        Dimension d = component.getSize();

        if (d.width == 0 || d.height == 0) {
            d = component.getPreferredSize();
            component.setSize(d);
        }

        layoutComponent(component);
    }

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(region.width, region.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();

    if (!component.isOpaque()) 
    {
        g2d.setColor(component.getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(region.x, region.y, region.width, region.height);
    }

    g2d.translate(-region.x, -region.y);
    component.paint(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    return image;
}


public static void layoutComponent(Component component) 
{
    synchronized (component.getTreeLock()) 
    {
        component.doLayout();

        if (component instanceof Container) 
        {
            for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) 
            {
                layoutComponent(child);
            }
        }
    }
}


public JPanel getvidComp()
{

         Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER,true);

         try
         {
            mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new File(videoFile).toURL());

            mediaPlayer.realize();

            mediaPlayer.prefetch();

            JPanel video=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            video.add(mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent()) ;

            mediaPlayer.start();

            return video;

         }

         catch( Exception d)
         {
             return null;

         }
}



public static Image makeColorTransparent( Image im, final Color color) 
{
    ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() 
    {
          public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;


          public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) 
          {
                Color c=new Color(rgb);

                int red=c.getRed();
                int green=c.getGreen();
                int blue=c.getBlue();

                //if(red<140 && green<140 && blue<140)
                {
                    int alpha=Math.max(Math.max(red , green), Math.max(green, blue))*3;
                    c=new Color(red , green , blue , alpha>255 ?255 :alpha );
                }

                return c.getRGB();
            }
      }; 

    ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TransparentVideo();
}

}
```